# using jboss and getting following exception

Tags: java, jboss, ejb-3.0

javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)]

Comment: 1. We all have urgent things to do 2. Posting "it's urgent" doesn't help to get faster answers. 3. However, posting a well written question in proper english, joining a full stacktrace, formatting your code might help.

Answer (score 1):

Try enabling java security:

In the Admin console go to security --> global security configuration
[x] enforce Java security

After that restart the server.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Today I faced this error.

Actually it was due to a LDAP credentials problem. My LDAP server was not working properly and that's the reason that there was a problem in the connection.

You should also check your LDAP, to resolve the issue.